# how do I overcome authentication failed error on git?

Tags: git, authentication, push

I'm trying to push local repo contents to the remote repo which is on bitbucket. I get a bitbucket dialogue box with username entered (but that is not my correct username ), asking for the password. but I get this as error:

```
$ git push
remote: Invalid username or password
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://bitbucket.org/88888888/8888888.g
```

Comment: Plsss help meee :((((((

Answer (score 0):

Firstly to avoid conflict config git using this command

```
 $ git config --global user.name "yourusername"
$ git config --global user.email "yourmail@example.com"
```

At the command line, make sure you've changed into the repository directory.

Enter git push at the command line to push your commits from your local repository to Bitbucket. To be specific about exactly where you're pushing, enter git push  . This command specifies you're pushing to:

remote_server — the name of the remote server. In most cases, origin indicates that you're pushing to Bitbucket.

branch_name — the repository branch where you made your changes and want to push them. A branch allows you do work on a set of code for your repository separate from the main [codebase](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/learn-git-with-bitbucket-cloud).

If prompted for authentication, enter your Bitbucket username and password.
In this example, origin is the remote server and master is the branch where you're [pushing](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/push-updates-to-a-repository-221449525.html):

In git repo

`git push`

or

`git remote origin "repo link"
     git push origin master`

In mercurial repo

`hg add --all
hg commit -m "message"
 hg push`